# How to simply send an SMS with Twilio with Xcode 9/iOS 11?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to simply send a text message to a phone number using my Twilio credentials in a Swift iOS app I'm coding in Xcode.

I tried the following popular [tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/11/how-to-send-an-sms-from-ios-in-swift.html), however since I'm using the latest version of Xcode (Version 9.0.1 (9A1004) and iOS 11.0, and the tutorial was designed with an older version of both, the last step (sending an SMS) in not working.

Any ideas on how to fix this for the latest Xcode/Swift/iOS?

I have the following warning messages in build time, if it helps.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked into a comment on the tutorial page and was able to solve the problem.

Before installing the podfile (before executing the 'pod install' command), I modified the text in the podfile which specifies the Alamofire version to a higher version (it was orignally 4.0 from the repo):

```
"pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'"
```

That was sufficient for the SMS to send but the tutorial also recommended to modify the bottom of the sendData function to:

```
Alamofire.request("YOUR_NGROK_URL/sms", method: .post, parameters: parameters, 
headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
print(response.response)
```